# How to convert String Base64 to url in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

i want to convert string Base64 to url for saving url in database bcz base64 lot of lines its time consuming

Comment: An url is mostly one line. And a base64 encoded url too.

Answer (score 0):

o convert a file to base64 in Kotlin, you can use the Base64 class from the java.util package. Here's an example:

```
import java.io.File
import java.util.Base64

fun fileToBase64(file: File): String {
    val bytes = file.readBytes()
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes)
}
```

And to convert a base64 string back to a file, you can use the Base64 class again, along with the FileOutputStream class from the java.io package. Here's an example:

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream

import java.util.Base64

fun base64ToFile(base64: String, file: File) {
    val bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64)
    val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
    fos.write(bytes)
    fos.close()
}
```